# How to get Bundle of xcframework that is in Pods

Tags: swift, cocoapods, xcframework

I need the Bundle of xcframework that is inside of pod. This is the structure:[image]

And in code I need to get something like this:

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "frameworkId")
```

I tried to add id in podfile like this:

```
 spec.info_plist = { 'CFBundleIdentifier' => 'com.myorg.unityFramework' }
 spec.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER': 'com.myorg.unityFramework' }
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Did you try a fully qualified name of the bundle, something like `Bundle(identifier: "com.myorg.unityFramework")`?

Comment: yes and it didn't work

Comment: in that case I think you may need to copy a bundle from pod to your app during the pod install. I don't know if there's a better solution, but this at least could be a workaround